# Cannot SSH to Ubuntu 18.04 After Switching from gdm3 to lightdm

Tags: ssh, lightdm

Setup new Ubuntu 18.04 server with default gdm3. Installed openssh-server and was able to SSH to the server.

Installed Teamviewer 15 and encountered issue where it fails to connect, and the solution provided by Teamviewer staff was to change the display manager from gdm3 to lightdm.

I did so and resolved the connection via Teamviewer issue, but now I can no longer SSH to the server. Is openssh-server incompatible with lightdm?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you be more specific than "can no longer SSH"? What happens, exactly (connection times out? authentication fails?). Your SSH client should have some options for additional debug information (`ssh -v` or `ssh -vv`) that may help. FWIW I am using lightdm on Ubuntu 18.04 and can SSH to it no problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is openssh-server incompatible with lightdm?

`openssh-server` is not incompatible with `lightdm` At this writing I am ssh'd into a Lubuntu 18.04 box.

applicable outputs of `apt policy`

```
lightdm:
  Installed: 1.26.0-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.26.0-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.26.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

gdm3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.6
  Version table:
     3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.6 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     3.28.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```